# ASP.NET 404 Response Text Chinese-like

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

When loading a page containing references to non-existing URL's using  tags, I see a strange text reply from the server.
The server does return status code 404 as expected, but it also includes a text response with chinese-like characters.

Is the server infected, or is the error message just in a different language than english ... ?
If infected, how can I find out where?

Here is an example of the text replies. It seems that the reply is identical for each 404 error, although a part of it changes when a different filetype is not found.

> 㰡䑏䍔奐䔠桴浬⁐啂䱉䌠∭⼯圳䌯⽄呄⁘䡔䵌‱⸰⁓瑲楣琯⽅丢•桴瑰㨯⽷睷⹷㌮潲术呒⽸桴浬ㄯ䑔䐯硨瑭氱⵳瑲楣琮摴搢㸍਼桴浬⁸浬湳㴢桴瑰㨯⽷睷⹷㌮潲术ㄹ㤹⽸桴浬∾ഊ㱨敡搾ഊ㱭整愠桴瑰ⵥ煵楶㴢䍯湴敮琭呹灥∠捯湴敮琽≴數琯桴浬㬠捨慲獥琽楳漭㠸㔹ⴱ∯㸍਼瑩瑬放㐰㐠ⴠ䙩汥⁯爠摩牥捴潲礠湯琠景畮搮㰯瑩瑬放ഊ㱳瑹汥⁴祰攽≴數琯捳猢㸍਼ℭⴍ੢潤祻浡牧楮㨰㭦潮琭獩穥㨮㝥活景湴ⵦ慭楬示噥牤慮愬⁁物慬Ⱐ䡥汶整楣愬⁳慮猭獥物昻...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a character encoding issue. It is a ASCII file that is being interpretted as a 2byte character encoding and thus you are getting the strange characters.

To translate it I copied the text to notepad. Saved it as Unicode-Big Endian and then used a hex editor to strip the first two characters (that tell it that it is unicode). Opening it again gave me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/> <title>404 - File or directory not found.</title> <style type="text/css"> <!-- body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

You would need to look into things to see if it is declaring the wrong content type in an HTML header (the content type in the meta tag looks correct) or something else is causing it problems.